# conditionalPanel does not work

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame that I want to show in a shiny app. I use some `selectInput` function to subset my data. I also want to use the function `conditionalPanel` to show only parts of my data. Depending of the selected cannel. Unfortunately the approach I am using does not show any table. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Hope all brackets are in the right position cause I changed my code a little bit for the public.

Data:

```
  data_test = data.frame(ID = c ("1","2","3","4","5"),
                  product = c("A","B","C","A","C"),
                  milieu = c("good","medium","bad","medium","bad"),
                  online = c(1,0,1,1,0),
                  ooh = c(0,1,0,1,1),
                  event = c(1,1,0,0,0))
```

UI:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("product milieu"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("select",
                 selectInput("select_milieu",
                             label = "Milieu",
                 choices = list("good",
                                "medium",
                                "bad")
                 ),
                 selectInput("select_product", 
                             label = "Product",
                             choices = list("A", 
                                            "B", 
                                            "C")
                 ),
                 selectInput("select_channel", 
                             label = "channel",
                             choices = c("online",
                                         "ooh",
                                         "event"))),
    mainPanel("My table",
              textOutput("output_milieu"),
              textOutput("output_product"),
              conditionalPanel(condition = "select_cannel == 'online'",
                               tableOutput("gapminder_table_online")),
              conditionalPanel(condition = "select_cannel == 'ooh'",
                               tableOutput("gapminder_table_ooh")),
              conditionalPanel(condition = "select_cannel == 'event'",
                               tableOutput("gapminder_table_event"))
              )
  )
))
```

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$gapminder_table_online <- renderTable({ 
    subset(data_test[,2:4],
           milieu == input$select_milieu & product == input$select_product)

  })

  output$gapminder_table_event <- renderTable({ 
    subset(data_test[,c(2,3,5)],
           milieu == input$select_milieu & product == input$select_product)

  })

  output$gapminder_table_ooh <- renderTable({ 
    subset(data_test[,c(2,3,6)],
           milieu == input$select_milieu & product == input$select_product)

  })

  output$output_milieu <- renderText({
    paste("milieu", input$select_milieu)
  })
  output$output_product <- renderText({
    paste("product", input$select_product)
  })
  output$output_cannel <- renderText({
    paste("cannel", input$select_cannel)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions have a typo (missing 'h' in 'select_channel') and also don't specify the input variable in full. Update them as shown below and then it should work as desired:

```
...
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.select_channel == 'online'",
                           tableOutput("gapminder_table_online")),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.select_channel == 'ooh'",
                           tableOutput("gapminder_table_ooh")),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.select_channel == 'event'",
                           tableOutput("gapminder_table_event"))
...
```

I feel I should note however, that it looks like there are definitely other problems with your code as well.